# QGIS 3.4.5 print composer: doesn't print DIN A0

Tags: qgis-3, print-composer, printing, qgis-print-layouts

I want to find a way to print a map with a raster layer in greyscale (GeoTIFF) and two vector layers in shp-format.

I created a map layout and went to the page properties (right-click on the canvas) to enter the Page Size A0. Exporting the layout to pdf results in a map DIN A4.

Can somebody tell me about the settings I have to change in detail so that I can plot my map?

Comment: I can't reproduce it on 3.4.3, could you post your full page properties ?

Comment: What about a update ? Currently latest version is 3.4.13.


On my 3.4.12 works fine, i work a lot with export especially A3, A4 or A0, that you described never occurred before.


Where do you see you pdf export is a A4?